# Use access token to create a facebook cookie?

Tags: android, facebook, cookies, webview, facebook-access-token

I have an app which uses the `Facebook SDK` for various stuff (sharing, like etc).

My problem is that; inside my app, I also show an `WebView` which exposes a webpage with `Facebook Comments` (Social Plugin). My problem is that, a user which login to facebook using the `Facebook SDK` also has to login to facebook inside the `WebView`.

So my question is: Is there any way to use an `access-token` (or any other way) to create a facebook session cookie that I can set so that the user is also logged in to facebook inside the `WebView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use an access token to create an FB cookie. This is by design and is for user security.

Comment: I also spoke with the Facebook "staff" about this and as you say, it's not possible. The only "way" to do this is if the user is using the WebView Facebook Login instead of the native Facebook app, but it will only be shown when native app is not installed.

Comment: Even with a webview, the SDK will clear the cookies after login is complete.

Comment: That is not true. I tried it and the cookies will still be there after the login.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Unity Facebook SDK 6.1.0 (not sure what internal version that corresponds to)

Comment: ah, 6.1 uses the old v3 of the SDK, which didn't have that behavior.